# Problem with finding bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

i just bought a new laptop and had install elementary os as a main boot. But i have a problem with bluetooth on my laptop. It keeps searching and no others bluetooth device detected. In this case , i want to send a file from my computer to my phone. Anyone have a solution?please help

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 1):

Resize your Bluetooth window (Device search) , it's probably the size of device list.