# Bluetooth can not find any devices

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

I have an Asus ***X541UJ***.
When I try to discover for a device the Discover Device Window doesn't shows nothing even if it leaves it open for several minutes. I've already tried to resize the Discover Device Window but same.
The same happens using **blueman**.

The bluetooth seems unlocked:

```
giuseppe@giuseppe-X541UJ:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

While when checking the status I have this error:

```
giuseppe@giuseppe-X541UJ:~$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar 2018-06-26 10:14:58 CEST; 17min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1553 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service                                                                                                                                                                           
           └─1553 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd                                                                                                                                                                      

giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Not enough free handles to register service                                                                                                                        
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Not enough free handles to register service                                                                                                                        
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Current Time Service could not be registered                                                                                                                       
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)                                                                                                                           
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Not enough free handles to register service                                                                                                                        
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Not enough free handles to register service                                                                                                                        
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Sap driver initialization failed.                                                                                                                                  
giu 26 10:14:58 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)                                                                                                                            
giu 26 10:15:06 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource                                                                                                   
giu 26 10:15:06 giuseppe-X541UJ bluetoothd[1553]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

I have already searched the net but I can not find a solution.

I've also tried to change linux-firmware but it does not change anything, now I have the version: **1.157.18**.
While for the kernel version: **4.15.0-23-generic**.

I am also attaching some general information on my pc if they can be useful:

```
giuseppe@giuseppe-X541UJ:~$ inxi -F                                                                                                                                                                                      
System:    Host: giuseppe-X541UJ Kernel: 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome 3.18.5
           Distro: elementary 0.4 loki
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: X541UJ v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X541UJ v: 1.0 Bios: American Megatrends v: X541UJ.302 date: 03/30/2017
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-7500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 600 MHz 2: 566 MHz 3: 597 MHz 4: 588 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 5916
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK208M [GeForce 920M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
Audio:     Card Intel Device 9d71 driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k4.15.0-23-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller driver: r8169
           IF: enp2s0f2 state: down mac: 60:45:cb:b6:2c:1a
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8723be
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 3c:a0:67:2b:25:29
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 250.1GB (40.4% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 250.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 221G used: 87G (42%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.47GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 261 Uptime: 26 min Memory: 2763.0/7858.7MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

This problem has afflicted me for months.
**Thank you all for your help**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but i solved it, like this:

1) I checked `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`
it gave me the result `Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found` i'ts commonly on combined wifi+bluetooth devices (especially Broadcom) [thanks for this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/problem-with-finding-bluetooth-device?rq=1)

2) Then i found *.hcd file from [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd) and download it

3) Then I copy downloaded *.hcd file to /lib/firmware/brcm

That's it, Don't forget to reboot after all!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this Stack Overflow answer 
[bluez 5.30: “Not enough free handles to register service” error in starting bluetoothd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891254/bluez-5-30-not-enough-free-handles-to-register-service-error-in-starting-blue#34811925)
and [the thread mentioned there](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195886&p=2)?

Comment: Thank you for your answare. I solved the problem with an external bluetooth adapter. I think it's a compatibility problem with the internal adatadactor of my notebook.